# ANONYMOUS FUNCTION -in- IF statement -inside- FOR loop -not working! WHY?

Tags: function, if-statement, for-loop, call

my first post on stackoverflow!!!

I am not sure why my function() is not working in the if(statment) inside the for loop...

I understand ways around it. That I could just add a var answer and console.log that in the first anonymous function, BUT I want to learn why the function is not working... HELP!

I've been learning bind, call, apply and wanted to create this example to try it and stumbled upon this question.

```
var fruits = [];

var Fruit = function(name, color, quantity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.quantity = quantity;
};

addFruit = function(name, color, quantity) {
    fruits.push(new Fruit(name, color, quantity));
}

// filled fruits[] with objects.
addFruit("strawberry", "red", 20);
addFruit("watermelon", "green", 5);
addFruit("orange", "orange", 10);

// trying to console.log "an" instead of "a" because it preceeds "orange"
var greet = function() {
    var vowels = "aeiou";
    for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
        if (this.name.charAt(0) === vowels.charAt(i)) {
  // here is where this function does not work...
            function() {
                console.log("I am an " + this.name);
            };
            break;
        }
        else {
            function() {console.log("I am a " + this.name)}
        }
    }
}

greet.call(fruits[2])
```

Comment: FORGOT TO MENTION WHY I USED A FUNCTION! 2 reasons.                1. I was posting "I am a orange" as well as "I am an orange" in the log. Not what I wanted.                                                                                   and 2. I did not want to post "I am a strawberry" in the console 5 times since the "S" in strawberry is not a vowel.

Comment: Where do you ever call the anonymous function that "doesn't work"?

Comment: if (this.name.charAt(0) === vowels.charAt(i)) {
  // here is where this function does not work...   ***************
            function() {                                             ***********
                console.log("I am an " + this.name);
            };

Comment: Is that correct, that you use === instead of == ?

Comment: Please tag questions with the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You define a function:

```
function() {
    console.log("I am an " + this.name);
};
```

But you never *call* that function.  And since it's anonymous, you have no way to refer to it after it's been defined.  So you'd have to call it directly in that definition:

```
(function() {
    console.log("I am an " + this.name);
})();
```

Which is kind of silly, since the function just does on thing and then falls out of scope.  You might as well just, well, do that one thing directly:

```
console.log("I am an " + this.name);
```

No need for a function here at all, anonymous or otherwise.

Comment: How would you recommend for me to change my code, so that 1. the for loop is there, 2. and the if statement. ------ Where the answer will only be one console.log of either "A" if the next word does not start with a vowel, and "AN" if it does.

Comment: @sergysurge: That's a bit outside the scope of the original question here, and very broad and open-ended.  What I would recommend is that you step through the code in a debugger and examine the logic/values as it executes.  This will help you determine where the code isn't doing what you expect it to do and what the state of the system is at that time.